# Как вытащить определённый путь к файлу через коллекции?

Tags: c#

У меня есть список путей в baseGame к файлам

```
public static HashSet<string> baseGame = new HashSet<string>();
// C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Games\Account Base
// C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Games\Connect
// и.т.д
```

Затем прохожу циклом

```
foreach (string files in baseGame) 
{
   ...
}
```

Можно ли сделать так чтобы из списка выбрать определённый путь к нужному файлу?
Например как-то так: (чтобы можно было выбрать по имени)

```
string acc = files["Account Base"];
string con = files["Connect"];
```

Comment: В смысле вам нужен словарь? Типа `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Comment: Может быть, мне просто нужен совет что можно использовать чтобы можно было сделать выборку по названию)

Comment: Можно использовать словарь.

Comment: что бы найти конкретное значение в списке можно воспользоваться linq методом`Where(x=>x.Contains("Account Base"))` или же как Вам посоветовал @tym32167 вместо списка использовать `Dictionary` где ключом будет имя файла

Comment: @Bald ```Where(x => x.EndsWith("Account Base"))``` возможно будет получше, т.к. проверяет действительно конец пути (т.е. как раз имя файла), а просто ключевое слово может и в середине пути встретиться

Comment: @SelfishCrawler да можно и так, но я бы предпочел вариант со словарем

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Работайте с путями [правильно](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netcore-3.1).

Найти можно так

```cs
string path = baseGame.First(x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "Account Base");
```

Словарь создать можно так

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dict = baseGame.ToDictionary(x => Path.GetFileName(x));
string path = dict["Account Base"];
```

А можно построить путь так

```cs
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, "Games", "Account Base");
```

Comment: я что-то поспешил поставить галочку, сижу сейчас уже ночь и не могу допереть, вот я использую `HashSet<string>` если пробую найти так: `string path = baseGame.First(x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "Account Base");` то у меня ошибка в х - не удаётся преобразовать `char` в `string`. Точно так же со вторым вариантом.  Вот как работать с путями спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: @ZidoX Если у вас появился новый вопрос, пожалуйста задайте его отдельно. Судя по ошибке `baseGame` у вас `string`, а не `HashSet<string>`. В моем ответе нет ошибки, зачем вы сняли галочку? Вам пример кода с выводом в консоль добаить? Или как еще доказать, что в ответе нет ошибки?